# Saving Scroll Position in HTA files

Tags: scrollbar, hta

i have a HTA application with a wide scroll bar and i want to save the position of scroll bar that user left the application ,any solution?

Comment: You can store the scroll position to a text file or even to the registry, and assign the value to the property when the content of the document has been loaded. What part is causing troubles? As it is, your question is too broad to answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file named scroll.js in the same folder as your HTA file, which will be used for stocking the scrollbar's position. Then insert following code in your HTA:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.onbeforeunload = function(){
          var myfile = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("scroll.js",2,true);
          myfile.WriteLine("document.body.scrollLeft = '" + document.body.scrollLeft + "';");
          myfile.WriteLine("document.body.scrollTop = '" + document.body.scrollTop + "';");
          myfile.Close();
     }
</script>
```

So that when you open the HTA it puts the scrollbar like the user left it, you need to insert this code right before the `</body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scroll.js"></script>
```

Comment: apparently, HTA does not support initialize scroll position

Comment: It works on my computer, so HTA should support it. What doesn't work? Does it show an error message or does it just not put back the scrollbars like you left them when closing?

Comment: your code work correctly but i try to use this values when the user open HTA for next time , scroll bar automatically scrolling to this positions (scrollTop) - and HTA does not support it

Comment: That's strange... I tried it on an HTA on my computer, as I said, and it woked just fine. Are you sure you didn't use something complicated like `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">` which can cause problems? Try the same thing on a simple HTA with only the things that I put in my answer and `<br><br><br><br>` etc in the body. Tell me if that works or not.